# How to implement job scheduling in python?

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I am implementing a task scheduling system in Django. User will select a task e.g. send email and will set a very specific time and date for task execution.

I found with Celery you can set up a task like

```
    @Task
    def email(address):
        // Send email logic
```

But how can I trigger it at specific time? For PeriodicTasks in celery one have to specify execution time and frequency upfront. How can i add execution date and time on the fly?

Is their any method in Celery e.g. add.schedule(date="SOME_DATA") or any other ways i can solve this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Periodic tasks is just only one feature of the celery. There are a hell lot of other features it supports.

You can use celery for this case. You can define a simple celery task to do something. Later when user submits/clicks a particular task, you just write a simple code to connect it to that task. Then that task will be executed by celery.

Checkout [first steps with django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django). Also, Celery is a very advanced async task delegation and processing system.

[Redis queue](http://python-rq.org/) is a much simpler async task processor and lightweight. If you have some simple tasks to do, you can use this